# Determine the htmlnode name/type (eg li)

Tags: c#, dom, html-agility-pack

How does one know if the `HtmlNode` I'm working with is an `<li>`?  I know the `NodeType` is an `Element` but how do you determine if that is an `<li>`

Let me know if there's any more information you need.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can check it like this, just use the `Name` property:

```
if( node.Name == "li" )
```